# como editar una columna de tipo "object" dentro de un dataframe en python

Tags: python, objeto

tengo este df de tipo object:

```
df

0       1 de 5
1       4 de 5
2       1 de 5
3       2 de 5
4       3 de 5
```

y me tengo que quedar solo con el resultado, dándome esto:

```
df_modificado

0       1 
1       4 
2       1 
3       2 
4       3
```

he probado a hacer `df.astype(str)[:1]` pero solo me da la primera fila y no edita el interior de la misma,
si hago `df.astype(str)[::,:1]` me salta este error:
`Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex`
que deberia hacer?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Vale, no importa mucho en realidad, lo comentaba porque no tienes un nombre para la columna o al menos no lo muestras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, si tu columna es de tipo `object` ya es `str` (pandas llama `object` a todo tipo que no sea nativo de NumPy, incluidos los tipos (clases) de Python estándar.

Para quedarte solo con el primer carácter debes indizar pero de forma vectorizada a través de `pandas.Series.str`:

```
import pandas as pd


data = ("1 de 5", "4 de 5", "1 de 5", "2 de 5", "3 de 5")
df = pd.DataFrame({"": data})

df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str[0]
```

Esto tiene un problema, si tu número tiene más de una cifra o hay un espacio antes, etc no obtendrás el número completo. Una opción muy simple pero mucho más flexible es usar `pandas.Series.str.extract` con regex:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ("1 de 5", "4 de 5", "1 de 5", "2 de 5", "3 de 5")

s = pd.Series(data)
new_s = s.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)

>>> new_s

0    1
1    4
2    1
3    2
4    3
dtype: object
```

Si tienes un DataFrame, puedes aplicar el mismo método sobre la columna dado que cada columna no deja de ser una Serie:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ("1 de 5", "4 de 5", "1 de 5", "2 de 5", "3 de 5")

df = pd.DataFrame({"": data})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
> 0   1 de 5
> 1   4 de 5
> 2   1 de 5
> 3   2 de 5
> 4   3 de 5
> ```

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
> 0   1
> 1   4
> 2   1
> 3   2
> 4   3
> ```

O podrías usar `pandas.series.str.replace` par eliminar lo que hay después del primer número.

Si quieres convertirlo a tipo `int` puedes aplicar `astype` una vez que te has quedado solo con el número.

La expresión no tiene mucha ciencia:

- `()` -> Grupo de captura.
- `\d` -> Clase de caracteres que incluye todos los dígitos del 0 al 9.
- `+`  -> Cuantificador, una o más veces.

Comment: muchas gracias crack!!!